# How can i get facebook referrer without $_SERVER["HTTP_REFERER"]

Tags: javascript, php

Can anyone tell me a security method to get facebook referrer without http referer?

Can be in PHP and Javascript.

Comment: What specifically are you trying to accomplish here? Why can't you use `$_SERVER[“HTTP_REFERER”]` if you say you can use PHP?

Comment: what do you mean, "facebook referer"? What page someone clicked on a link to reach your site? That'd be the http referer, and would be the only way to tell.

Comment: @PatrickQ i'm creating a website, but i just want traffic from facebook, and others website has fake referer traffic. I just want real traffic from facebook. But i can't use captcha.

Comment: If someone has intentionally (and intelligently) blanked or spoofed the referer, there's not really much you can do about that.

Comment: That makes it difficult :/

Comment: If you explain us, what do you want to achive with more details, maybe we can suggest you alternative ways. " i just want traffic from facebook". Why?

Comment: because i work with ads and the ads needs just facebook traffic. but i have users spoofing the referer